# How Can an Always-False PostgreSQL Query Run for Hours?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-deadlocks

I've been trying to debug a slow query in another part of our system, and saw this query is active:

```
SELECT * FROM xdmdf.hematoma AS "zzz4" WHERE (0 = 1)
```

It has apparently been active for > 8 hours. With that `WHERE` clause, logically, this query should return zero rows. Why would a SQL engine even bother to evaluate it? Would a query like this be useful for anything, and if so, what could it be?

(`xdmdf.hematoma` is a view and I would expect `SELECT *` on it to take ~30 minutes under non-locky conditions.)

This statement:

```
explain select 1 from xdmdf.hematoma limit 1
```

(no `analyze`) has been running for about 10 minutes now.

Comment: Is `hematoma` a view?

Comment: why yes, yes it is.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the one execution plan for the query using `where false` and another one without that condition. Please add them as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Have you double checked that the `state` in `pg_stat_activity` is `active`, not `idle`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe its state is `active`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will try. So far, all my attempts to use `explain` on that view are taking "forever" just like the original query.

Comment: A simple `explain` should not be a problem as it does not run the statement (as `explain (analyze)` would)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That makes sense; nevertheless, this `explain select 1 from xdmdf.hematoma limit 1` (no analyze) has been running for about 10 minutes now.

Comment: @kojiro . . . Hmmm . . . Perhaps there is some strange deadlock or locks in the database.  That might require more investigation.

Comment: You can find out if the query is waiting for a lock by looking at `wait_event` and `wait_event_type` in `pg_stat_activity` while the query is "active"

Comment: They are all waiting for locks, definitely. But my question is about whether or not there's any value from a query that has `WHERE (1 = 0)` and, I guess, this behavior shows that at least, PostgreSQL does not eliminate running such a query.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. It takes forever to plan the statement, because you changed some planner settings and the view definition is so complicated (partitioned table?).

   This is the unlikely explanation.
2. A concurrent transaction is holding an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on a table involved in the view definition.

   Terminate any such concurrent transactions.